Tensorflow lite multipose model documentation doesnt match model requirements
In the kaggle page for the movenet multipose tflite page it requests for a tensor of dynamic shape 1xHxWx3, where H and W need to be a multiple of 32 and the larger dimension is recommended to be 256.
Link to kaggle page: https://www.kaggle.com/models/google/movenet/tfLite/multipose-lightning-tflite-float16
However once the model is downloaded the sample code provided in android says
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 1, 1, 3), DataType.UINT8)

The buffer isnt of dynamic type and it doesnt take parameters of 256 or any other value besides 1 actually. Snippet of current is given below. Currently it is resized to 1,1 as resizing to any other size causes errors
        imageProcessor = new ImageProcessor.Builder().add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(1, 1)).build();

bitmap = textureView.getBitmap();
                TensorImage tensorImage = new TensorImage(DataType.UINT8);
                tensorImage.load(bitmap);
                tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage);

                int[] shape = new int[] {1,1,1,3};

               TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(shape,DataType.UINT8);
                //TensorBuffer inputFeature0 =TensorBuffer.createDynamic(DataType.UINT8);
                inputFeature0.loadBuffer(tensorImage.getBuffer());

                Log.d("Buffer created", "true");

                AutoModel1.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);

                TensorBuffer temp =  outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                float[] outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer().getFloatArray();

This is doubly weird because the singlepose model requests for 1,192,192,3 and the sample code matches and works with it its only for this multipose model where if you try to create a dynamic type tensor buffer or a buffer with a different shape it doesn't work. It compiles and runs in its current state but the keypoints are just drawn on the top left in a random shape that doesn't alter but like earlier the singlepose model works fine drawing the points accurately. Drawing code below
 Bitmap mutable = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutable);
                int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                int x = 0;

                //see line198 in tflie sample app for ref on looping through coordinates

                Log.d("output__", String.valueOf(outputFeature0.length));
                while (x <= 51) {
                    float score_val =  outputFeature0[x+2];

                    Log.d("score values", String.valueOf(Math.abs(score_val)));
                    //if (outputFeature0[x+2] > 0.3f) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(Math.abs(outputFeature0[x+1] * w), Math.abs(outputFeature0[x] * h), 10f, paint);

                     //}
                    x += 3;
                }

                imageView.setImageBitmap(mutable);
            }
        });

